# Not Found Alert while using DWR on a AppFog deployed App

Tags: configuration, dwr

While implementinf an app with DWR, I succesfully deployed an app in "AppFog" but I noticed a problem. Inmediately after loading, an alert raise up with this message: "Not Found". I would like to know why is this hapenning and how I can solve this...

If this is cmplex and you kneed more info, I'll be around... Thankx

Comment: At least some code... is this happening when making a dwr call?

Comment: No... I just copy and paste a basic example... But the error isn't hapenning while making a dwr call... It raise up just when the page finish the loading process... So I'm a little bit confused... Maybe here we can find an explanation http://blog.intropedro.es/es/tema/dwr but I can't get through... Thankx for answering